# How to make sequence in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a simple sequence of two actions but Xcode is saying that I have an extra argument in call. I tried to translate Apples Obj-C example into Swift and it's not going very well. What am I doing wrong?

```
func dead() {
    let animateAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(self.catArray, timePerFrame: 0.09)
    let ending = SKAction.runBlock(self.gameOver)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence(actions: animateAction, ending)
    self.cat.runAction(sequence)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence method of SKAction requires an Array of AnyObject. To fix this, you will need to call the method with the two actions you declared earlier in an array like this:

```
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([animateAction, ending])
self.cat.runAction(sequence)
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked perfectly, thank you! I forgot about braces.